# Performance Issues while building custom DatePicker

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

for my project I need to build an own, custom DatePicker. I can't just use the standard DatePicker, because I need features like selecting multiple dates, disabling special dates, etc.

I planned to build my own custom DatePicker as close to the standard DatePicker as possible.
Therefore I have decided to use a ViewPager in which I nest a custom View that holds a custom ViewHolder containing  just a TextView to Display the current Month and a RecyclerView to Display the Actual Days of the month in question.

The result looks something like that:

[image: The whole gridlike-structure is realized through a recyclerview (the names of the weekdays and the numbers of the dates), and the Name of the month is shown in a normal textview. The Arrow-Buttons are not part of the View, they are added directly through the activity.]

I don't think it is necessary to provide the whole code (adapters, layouts etc.) because the whole thing is fairly straight forward but if you need to see, I can add it after the fact.

Now to my problem: When I start the activity, the whole application stops for about 3 seconds, and I get the following logcat-output:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I narrowed the problem down to the RecyclerViews.
(when they are deactivated, there is no freezing/stuttering whatsoever)

When the activity starts, the application has to load 3 full Recyclerviews (because I set `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` )
and that initial loading causes the whole application to freeze for a short amount of time. After everything is loaded, the whole thing works completely lag-free.

To this problem I have 2 different solutions in mind:

1. Load the RecyclerViews in another Thread

   The idea is, that the activity starts, and the RecyclerViews are only shown, when they are loaded. This wouldn't be perfect, but at least the activity would start without causing the whole application to freeze.
2. Substitute the RecyclerViews with something better performing.

   Is there even a View/Structure that  a) enables me to display a gridlike Structure and b) is better performing than a recyclerview?
   Initially I chose the RecyclerView for displaying the days, because I thought that the Standard DatePicker uses it too, but after some digging in the integrated classes I am no longer so sure about this.
   To me it seemed like the days are drawn without any View whatsoever. (I could be wrong about that)

Is there any possiblity, that one of those ideas could be working?

And if not, is there another way to fix the performance-issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JonasLochmann Do you think this approach would be worth the effort, and if so, can you give me any direction in which I can start investigating?

Comment: Yeah, maybe that is the problem. 
I'll try to put more work behind that, maybe I'll be able to solve it without creating a custom view.
Thanks. :)